# -1 to the power of any irrational number is an imaginary number

Tags: number-theory

I am sorry if this is a trivial question. But, just to make sure I miss nothing, the following is true, isn't it?
$$\forall r \in \left(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\right) : (-1)^r \notin\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: What's $\overline{\mathbb Q}$? Maybe you mean $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: Yes, I mean the set of irrational numbers: $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You should edit accordingly, then!

Comment: I have seen $\bar {\Bbb Q}$ as the notation for the irrational numbers in some texts. I would say the OP could keep it but might want to clarify.

Comment: @MattDickau: It's okay. Just to make the statement clearer, I have replaced the symbol accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Possible values for $(-1)^r$ where $r$ is irrational are all complex (not necessarily imaginary) and none of them lie on the real axis. (Below, $k$ is an integer, so $(2k+1)r$ can never be an integer by irrationality of $r$.)
$$(-1)^r=\exp ((2k+1)r\pi i)$$